# View function did not return a response (flask)

Tags: python, flask

не вьеду, где я не туда тыкнул

routes.py

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from app.forms import LoginForm
from app.models import User

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Pavel'}
    posts = [
        {
            'autor': {'username': 'Loh'},
            'body': 'Ebat` kolotit`',
        },
        {
            'autor': {'username': 'Petya'},
            'body': 'Nu nihuya sebe'
        },
        {
            'autor': {'username': 'Vasya'},
            'body': 'Ebushki Vorobushki'
        }
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, posts=posts)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Не валидные данные')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

werkzeug

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/kiril/microblog/codenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после

```
return redirect(next_page)
```

нужно вернуть шаблон

```
return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

Логично, представление `login()` возвращает `None`, если форма не прошла валидацию.

Comment: ну да, и вернет flash!!?!?

Comment: Нет. Если метод `validate_on_submit()` в условии `if form.validate_on_submit():` вернёт ложное значение, то функция `login()` вернёт `None`, так как нет ветки `else`.

Comment: c else возвращает тоже самое

Comment: @htaccess с каким именно else?